# Make a foreign key field in a django form read-only, and still enable the form to be submitted

Tags: html, django, forms, readonly

How do I make a foreign key field in a form read only but still allow this field to be recognized as valid once the form is submitted?  According to W3C, disabled fields are left out once the form is submitted....using the code below, I can set the field as disabled, thus readonly, but my form  doesn't go through

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(IssuesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['vehicle'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Ideas....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the Django or Python syntax, however, an input field of type="hidden" might be what you're looking for.  If you wanted to still display the value using a disabled field, you could do that too, and rely on the hidden field for the actual value.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this question after many other solutions didn't seem to work. Here's example code of how I got it work successfully using the "hidden" suggestion, in case it's helpful to anyone else.

```
class EditExifForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditExifForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].widget.attrs['hidden'] = True    # This is the solution
        # Setting as 'readonly' didn't make a difference
        # Setting as 'disabled' made the form not update the database

    class Meta:
        model = exif
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TechCustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.initial['status'] == 'Done' or self.initial['status'] == 'Reject':
        self.fields['status'].disabled = True
```

Its work for Model ForeignKey Field

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can try the hidden field...I knew this was a possibility, but I wanted to be sure there was no other way

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem and I used JavaScript to solve